# Installing g++-7 without access to the internet

Tags: apt, wireless, package-management, dependencies, g++

I have a problem ;) My wi-fi adapter has stopped working out of the blue and since I've no wire here I can't access the Internet from my Ubuntu machine. I've found the following command to fix the adapter:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source -y
```

and almost managed to make it work by manually copying the required archives using USB stick (I also have MacBook Pro here with Internet access). Right now I've the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 bcmwl-kernel-source : Depends: dkms but it is not going to be installed
 g++ : Depends: g++-7 (>= 7.4.0-1~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Is there any way to work it around using just an USB stick?

Comment: Use Grub menu at boot, Advanced options to boot into another kernel and see if wifi works

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy31! I've tried but to no avail.